# Ember values in Component not binding

Tags: ember.js

I have an object that gets entered into a component

```
{{edit-general item=item}}
```

Inside this component, you can edit the values of an array.

```
{{#each value in item.values}}
    <div class="input-field col s6 l6">
        {{input type='text' value=value}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

However, this value does not bind. The item gets changed inside the component, but this change does not affect the model.

How would I make this work the way I want it to?

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/modunewoca/31/edit?html,output

Comment: Please post your entire code in a JSBin. This usually works.

Comment: I have added a JSBin showing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind simple strings and objects, you need to wrap all this into Ember.Object, that allows bindings.

```
function m(data) {
  return Ember.Object.create({
    data: data
  });
}

var model = [Ember.Object.create({
  field: 'ethnicity',
  values: [m('African American'), m('Asian'), m('Caucasian'), m('Hispanic'), m('Other')]
}), Ember.Object.create({
  field: 'gender',
  values: [m('Male'), m('Female'), m('Other'), m('Prefer not to disclose')]
})];
```

```
  {{#each item in model}}
    <div><b>{{item.field}}</b></div>
    {{#each value in item.values}}
      <div>{{value.data}}</div>
      <div>{{edit-general value=value.data}}</div>
    {{/each}}
    <br><br>
  {{/each}}
```

Updated JSBin: http://jsbin.com/xebizeyedu/2/edit